# video_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ is not a function

Tags: angular, webpack, video.js

i am using video.js library in angular version 8 and getting error

> TypeError: video_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ is not a function

```
@ViewChild('myplayer', {static: false}) videoElement:ElementRef ;
import * as videojs from 'video.js';

ngAfterViewInit(){
this.initPlayer();
}

initPlayer(){
const video = videojs(this.videoElement.nativeElement);  
}
```

Comment: Where did you found this library? Is there a GH page?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi yes you can find this library at GitHub https://github.com/videojs/video.js

Comment: Thank you, I'll look up to this

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
import * as videojs from 'video.js';
```

to

```
import videojs from 'video.js';
```